# Spring Boot static resource access

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm working with a Spring Boot web application. I'm facing problem in accessing static resources like CSS, JS and image files.

When I'm not having any `@Controller classes`, the static resource request is successfully handled by `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`.

But after marking a class with `@Controller` static resource URs are directed only to the method inside that class (through `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`).

Am I missing some configuration?
My controller class as below,

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {


@RequestMapping(name="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
    return "index";
}


@RequestMapping(name="login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login() {
    return "home";
}
```

In my .HTML file Im referring the static resources as below,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
th:href="@{bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css}">
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"
th:src="@{bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
th:src="@{jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js}"></script>
```

Directory structure as below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siPqz.png)

I tried to to add resource like below also,

```
@Configuration
public class XbrlWebApp implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");

}
```

but this also not working. When the static resource is accessed, with the url like,

> http://localhost:8080/{contextpath}/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

it returns the same html page content instead of the css file.

Comment: What is the url and what is the mapping? dont you think those are important information?

Comment: sorry. I edited my question. Please help.

Comment: Can you try using mydomain/<context>/<resource type>/resource

Comment: `it returns the same html page content instead of the css file.` What is that HTML page, your's or some default springboot page?

Comment: it returns the index page.. whatever http request sent, its returning index.html page only

Comment: The configuration you've posted won't work indeed, because you're adding a resource handler for `/static/**` even though your URLs do not contain `/static/`. If you use your configuration, you should change the URLs to `http://localhost:8080/{contextPath}/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its completely my mistake.
In the @RequestMapping method,

```
@RequestMapping(name="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
return "index";
}
```

I used "name" attribute. It should be "value". Since there is no "value" attribute found, whatever GET http request came, everything redirected to the same method and it returns the index.html page. so static resources also get the same. Spring configurations working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JAR packaging , you don't need to configure anything as springboot automatically configures handling static content if you place everything under the static folder.Like put js files under : `resources/static/js` and the css under `resources/static/css` and the default implementation should take it up. And you can refer to it using the link like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="css/bootstrap.css"
th:href="@{bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css}">
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"
th:src="@{bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
```

Try the following configuration if you are using WAR packaging, for your directory structure :

```
@Configuration
public class XbrlWebApp implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
    .addResourceLocations("/resources/","classpath:/other-resources/","classpath:/static/");

}
```

and in the html use :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="resources/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
th:href="@{bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css}">
<script src="resources/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"
th:src="@{bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
th:src="@{jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js}"></script>
```

If you are creating a WAR , all your resources will be in effect copied to the `webapps/resources` folder , while preserving the folder structure.So try the above configuration.